# Refresh previous page dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, asp.net

I'm quite new to C# and asp.net and have been struggling for a few days to sort out what seems to be something simple. I've got two pages lets call it page1.aspx and page2.aspx

---

page1.aspx

I've got two dropdownlists with a continue button. Once the continue button is clicked it will populate data specified in my sql statement. On the first column I've got a hyperlink 'view' and in the last column I've got checkboxes which are disabled. Once I click on the view hyperlink it takes me to page2.aspx which has a button Tick and Untick which ticks the checkbox on page1.aspx

---

page2.aspx

On this page I've got three buttons (back, tick, untick) the tick and untick buttons is just to tick or untick the disabled checkboxes on page1.aspx. On the back button I'm trying a response.redirect('page1.aspx'); however when I get redirected the dropdownlist is empty and it doesnt repopulate the previous selected criteria to show the newly ticked or unticked checkbox.

---

What I've tried

1. I tried a function

```
    function fnHistory() {
        window.history.go(-1);
    }
```

on the back button of page2.aspx this does keep my dropdownlist values on page1.aspx however it doesnt display the newly ticked checkbox since the page needs to be refreshed and refreshing the page takes away the dropdown values.

2. I tried to do a page refresh every 5 seconds on the div where the sql data gets displayed this is however not a option as its just bad practice.
3. I've tried update panel on page 1 for the div where the sql data gets displayed however the trigger which should be the tick and untick button is on page2.aspx

Your help and advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything unique on page2 that you have to open it in another window?
What about opening the 2nd page in a modal? So you can get access to page1 directly.

Comment: Hi Szabii, yes page2 is unique please have a look at the hyperlink on page 1                                                               td = new TableCell();
                    td.Text = "<a href='MassUpdateESheetTSEdit.aspx?ProductID=" + rs["ProductID"].ToString().Trim() + "&ESheetEnquiryno=" + rs["ESheetEnquiryno"].ToString().Trim() + "&TickSheetHID=" + rs["TickSheetHID"].ToString().Trim() + "'>View</a>";
                    tr.Cells.Add(td);
The ID's get used to display the unique information on page 2

Comment: Open a modal on page1 with clicking on the hyperlink. A window will pop up and if you click on any button, just call a JS function which can be found on page1 so you'll be able affect to the checkbox. Here is a working fiddle for your example: https://jsfiddle.net/cLbohpy5/16/